# how to add some html tags to DisplayTag?

Tags: displaytag

how to add some html tag between `<displaytag:table>` and `</displaytag:table>`. Plz help me to custom it, thank you very much.

```
 <displaytag:table>
     **<div class="mycss">**  

     <displaytag:column />
       <displaytag:column />

      **</div>**
    </displaytag:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html) it doesn't appear that you can put HTML tags there. Then again, even HTML itself doesn't allow a `<div>` tag directly inside a `<table>` tag, so I'm not sure why you'd want to do this.

According to the [FAQ](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/faq.html#headers):

> How can I display static headers in a table, so that headers remain visible while user scrolls the table body?
>
> You can do that simply using css, adding an height and the overflow: scroll property to the tbody element. Unfortunately this will work perfectly in Netscape/Mozilla, but not in Internet Explorer.
>
> A table with a scrollable body can be made in Internet Explorer using javascript or a more complex css. [Here](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) you can find a good css example.

And some more info [here](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/display_tag_static_headers).

Comment: I want to add scrollable capability for table that's generated by DisplayTag :)

Comment: @trcrab please see my updated answer. It appears that it's "sort of" possible, but it doesn't always work.

Comment: thank for you help, it's cool, Is there another way to custom DisplayTag by extending java class (http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/apidocs/overview-summary.html )

Comment: @trcrab sorry I don't know. I'm not actually familiar with DisplayTag at all - I just learned about it 1 hour ago :)